# Using NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin in boundingRectWithSize:options:context: gets extra blank space

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I am using boundingRectWithSize:options:context: in iOS 7 to try to calculate the dynamic height of texts in a UITableViewCell. However, using this method and `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin` as the option I always get some extra space at the bottom and the top. If I switch to `NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics` the words would not wrap at the end of the line. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

For some lines that contain more texts the space will be much bigger. How can I resolve this? I use the following code to get the size of the frame of the UILabel that holds the texts:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithMaxSize:(CGSize)constrainedSize andFontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    self.paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    self.paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize],
                             NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: self.paragraphStyle.copy,
                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]};
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self attributes:dictionary];
    CGRect frame = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
    return frame.size;
};
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find out the issue ?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I'm having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

What if you **OR** the two options, since they are just bit fields... `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics`

So instead of:

```
CGRect frame = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
```

you have:

```
CGRect frame = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics context:nil];
```

?